# Why does the AndroidStudio3.0 enabled advanced profiling requires API level less than 26

Tags: android, api, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

When I enable the AndroidStudio3.0 profiling feature, the prompt text after the option is found.

> required for API level < 26 only

Why?

What happened to the higher API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that specifically enabling Android Studio 3.0 profiling is ONLY required for devices with API levels less than 26...

So it's just saying that it is not necessary to install if device/emulator you're using is new enough not to include the feature by default (26 or above).

Info [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hTC-fcVPtk).

Comment: If the API level is less than 26, this option needs to be enabled specifically. API level 26 or higher is not required because they are supported by default.
Can I understand in this way?

Comment: If the API level (of the target device) is less than 26, this option needs to be enabled specifically. API level 26 or higher is not required because they are supported by default. Can I understand in this way? YES! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.